# Codeigntier validation issue while using tank_auth

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter, tankauth

So I have a code here to validate the usernname exist or not, I'm using tank_auth library

```
if(! $this->tank_auth->is_username_available($username))
{
    $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check');
}
```

In the form validation file ( validation.php ) how can I call this message

```
'register_view' => array(
array(
    'field' => 'username',
    'label' => 'أسم المستخدم',
    'rules' => 'required|trim|max_length[20]|username_check'
),
```

I added username_check at the end isn't this right?

Comment: Have you extended the form validation library with the `username_check` validation method and set the message for it?

Comment: For more convinience, use `callback_username_check` instead `username_check`, then you can create `function username_check($str)` in your controller as a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

well it's easier to use

```
'rules' => 'required|trim|max_length[20]|is_unique[users.username]'
```

[Form validation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

and add your custom message here

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'Error Message');
```

I can see you are using Arabic it's better to check how to integrate language with default form validation messages as well